# Importing a module from another directory that isn't inside the current dir

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, relative-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── /scripts
|   ├── /data
|   |   └── files.xls
|   └── module.py
├── /interface
|   └── app.py
```

And I need to import a function from `module.py` into my `app.py`, but using
`from ..scripts.module.py import some_function` is not working. I'm running python from the root directory and always get this error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.
How can I make this import work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Imports consider _modules and packages on the Python path_, not directories. If you want to use relative imports, you'll need to structure your code as a [package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package).

Comment: thanks Brian. that link solved it